# Is there a single academic database for Management Information System /Decision Support System area?

Tags: phd, research-process, literature-review, databases

Until now, I have been gathering literature rather primitively (I think) by regularly searching with related keywords in Google, Google Scholar, and also some of the university resources like -

- Emerald Insight
- Ebsco
- Jstor
- IEEE
- ScienceDirect

And I'm not sure whether I find all the relevant literature and what else I need to be looking at.

Recently, I came to know that for certain fields there are dedicated databases that provide a unified source of research - which can be quite useful to perform a literature survey. Like SciFinder for Chemistry, NCBI for Biotech etc.

So, I'm wondering whether there is any such database in the field of  -Management Information System / Decision Support Systems.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is: **No**, there isn't.

This is simply because MIS/DSS research is often published in outlets which are more closer to the discipline of the context. For instance, many health informatics studies could also be found in the health outlets i.e., atypical MIS venues; or, a DSS study done in the context of nursing is most likely to be found in a nursing outlet, so on and so forth.